# Call-time pass-by-reference warning

Tags: php

```
    function heaviside(&$value, $key, &$array)
    {
            if($key > 0)
            $value = $array[$key-1].$array[$key];
    }

    function test_heaviside()
    {
            for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
            {
                    $array[$i] = $i;
            }
            array_walk($array, 'heaviside', &$array);
            print_r($array);
    }

    test_heaviside();
```

My problem is that the above code will generate this warning:

> PHP Warning:  Call-time
>   pass-by-reference has been deprecated
>   - argument passed by value;  If you would like to pass it by reference,
>   modify the declaration of
>   array_walk().  If you would like to
>   enable call-time pass-by-reference,
>   you can set
>   allow_call_time_pass_reference to true
>   in your INI file.  However, future
>   versions may not support this any
>   longer.

And if I remove & in &$array in my call to array_walk, this function will not return this correct result. In the first case, where it works, it returns this result:

> ```
> [0] => 0
> [1] => 01
> [2] => 012
> [3] => 0123
> [4] => 01234
> [5] => 012345
> [6] => 0123456
> [7] => 01234567
> [8] => 012345678
> [9] => 0123456789
> ```

Whereas if I remove & it returns:

> ```
> [0] => 0
> [1] => 01
> [2] => 12
> [3] => 23
> [4] => 34
> [5] => 45
> [6] => 56
> [7] => 67
> [8] => 78
> [9] => 89
> ```

I need help understanding this or simply to find a solution other than changing .ini.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're abusing `array_walk` here -- your callback function isn't actually returning the new value.  `array_walk` is intended to work with one and only one value from the target array, and can not work with anything by reference.

You can achieve the effect you're looking for by using a simple for loop:

```
// Set up the array.
    $array = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
        $array[$i] = $i;
// Process it, starting at the second element
    for($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++)
        $array[$i] = $array[$i - 1] . $array[$i];
    print_r($array);
```

Comment: Don't use count() in the loop declaration!  Count() is relatively expensive and it will be executed every time round the loop, making it slow.  Store the count to a variable first and use that instead.

Comment: Yeah, I was lazy when writing it.  :)

Answer (score 4):

From the [php manual about references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

> Note: There is no reference sign on a
>   function call - only on function
>   definitions. Function definitions
>   alone are enough to correctly pass the
>   argument by reference. As of PHP
>   5.3.0, you will get a warning saying that "call-time pass-by-reference" is
>   deprecated when you use & in
>   foo(&$a);.

This means that you can not tell an argument to be a reference. Only the function definition can do this. If you look at the [array_walk manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) you see that only the first argument is a reference, and the last cannot be.

So in the end, what you want is deprecated. You can either

- change the ini (which you don't want to)
- downgrade your php version
- remove the warning by setting the error level lower.
- write your own array_walk function that does take a reference as 3rd parameter