# PHP 5.4 Call-time pass-by-reference - How to fix it?

Tags: php, array-walk

I have the problem that I get the error

> PHP Fatal error: Call-time pass-by-reference has been removed in....

I discovered some similar questions e.g.

- [PHP 5.4 Call-time pass-by-reference - Easy fix available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8971261/php-5-4-call-time-pass-by-reference-easy-fix-available/8971301)
- [Call-time pass-by-reference warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5177802/call-time-pass-by-reference-warning)

But nothing offers a reals answers how situations be can solved where you NEED to declare the passed value as refference by runtime for e.g. buildin function which you cant change function declaration ??.

e.g.  for this example [third array_walk parameter as reference](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-walk.php#56897): ?

I tried to use this solution to change the indexes of my array with this code:

```php
function __reindex(&$v,$k, &$aReindexed) 
{ 
   $kNew = $k+100;
   $aReindexed[$kNew] = $v; 
}


$aTest = array(4,"f","_","test");
array_walk($aTest,"__reindex", &$aReindexed );
```

The [Code without the refference](https://3v4l.org/CXpQf) is not working (the new array is not changed and stays empty).

And the [Code with the refference](https://3v4l.org/SMHqg) it works, but not in php 5.4 and higher.

So whats the way so handle such situations ?

p.s. if anybody likes to say "declare the $k variable in your __reindex function as refference" then that wont work (that was the first way I tried)

Answer (score 0):

I found a way what maybe helps some people.

[Try this Code](https://3v4l.org/jIgLW)

```php
$aTest = array(4,"f","_","test");
$aReindexed = array();

array_walk($aTest, function(&$v,$k) use (&$aReindexed) { 
  $kNew = $k+100;
  $aReindexed[$kNew] = $v; 
} );

print_r($aReindexed);
```

This coud would work in php 5.4 and above.

But it works not for lower php versions, and you can not use it with an already existing (non-anonym) callback function, because the USE-Keyword only works when you create a new Closure function.